# invalid cursor state: cursor position is unknown

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb, ucanaccess

I am using uCanAccess library to insert a row into an existing MS Access table through a swing GUI. The code works fine till *rs.insertRow()*, after which the cursor cannot be set to anywhere.

Here is my code:

```
private void addRowBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

    try {
        rs.moveToInsertRow();
        System.out.println("moved to insert Row");

        rs.updateString(2, "jimmyHendrix");
        System.out.println("updated string");

        rs.updateInt(3, 5);
        System.out.println("updated int");

        rs.insertRow();
        System.out.println("Row Inserted");   // works great till here

        rs.moveToCurrentRow();                               // rs.getRow() returns a 0
        System.out.println("cursor moved to current row");   // This line does get printed

        rs.absolute(1);                       // Throws the above mentioned exception at any attempt to set the cursor position
        System.out.println("abs 1");          // Hence this line doesn't get printed.


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(accessGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

here is the creation and execution of the statement:

```
public class accessGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn;
Statement s;
ResultSet rs;
/**
 * Creates new form accessGUI
 */
public accessGUI() {
    initComponents();

    try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://d:/accessFiles/records.accdb;memory=true");
        s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT [RollNo],[Name],[class] FROM [schoolRecord]");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(accessGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the generated output which shows the exception stacktrace:

```
>--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ accessMaven ---
moved to insert Row
updated string
updated int
Row Inserted
cursor moved to current row
Aug 27, 2017 4:33:06 PM com.maxeejava.accessmaven.accessGUI addRowBtnActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 invalid cursor state: cannot FETCH NEXT, PRIOR, CURRENT, or RELATIVE, cursor position is unknown
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.absolute(UcanaccessResultSet.java:92)
    at com.maxeejava.accessmaven.accessGUI.addRowBtnActionPerformed(accessGUI.java:243)
    at com.maxeejava.accessmaven.accessGUI.access$500(accessGUI.java:19)
    at com.maxeejava.accessmaven.accessGUI$6.actionPerformed(accessGUI.java:116)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid cursor state: cannot FETCH NEXT, PRIOR, CURRENT, or RELATIVE, cursor position is unknown
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlExceptionSQL(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.absolute(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessResultSet.absolute(UcanaccessResultSet.java:90)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid cursor state: cannot FETCH NEXT, PRIOR, CURRENT, or RELATIVE, cursor position is unknown
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more
```

Upon checking the database, the new row does get added but any attempt at runtime to set the cursor position after insertion of new row fails.

Comment: Please show the exception stacktrace, and show how you create and execute the statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel edited the question to include what you had asked.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i got it going by using rs.close() followed by rs.executequery("xxx"). i don't think its the efficient way to do it, but it works for now.